# Dompdf Bug of div which is not follow the css

Tags: html, css, dompdf

The Dompdf has a bug that it does not base on the div css to scale size which the div has over the page size. I have tried the table which the css not work for it. How can i limit the size? 
[image]

Here is the code:
 **HTML**

```
<style>
.table {
        display: table;
        width:100px;
        padding:5px;
    }

    .row {
        display: table-row;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        width:100px;
    }

    .cell {
        display: table-cell;
        width:100px;
        border: 1px solid #000000;
        text-align:left;
        padding:3px;
    }
    .cell_DB{
     width:100px;
    }
</style>
    <div class="table cell_DB" border="0" cellpadding="3">
        <div class="row cell_DB" >
            <div class="cell cell_DB" >
                   Title
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row cell_DB">
            <div class="cell cell_DB">

                <p class="cell_DB">
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                    <br/>
                    <br/>

                </p>
            </div>      
        </div>
        <div class="row cell_DB">
            <div class="cell cell_DB">

                <p class="cell_DB" style="color: blue">

                </p>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<div style="width:80%;"> ....CODES... </div>` after `</style>` tag

Comment: It still same. no changes.

Comment: After you edit your post and i follow it, it still same.The style does not apply on the `div`

Answer (score 0):

This is currently solution which make the `display` to be `block`.

```
.cell_DB{
     display:block;
    }
<p style="word-wrap:break-word;width:98%;">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
```

Comment: dompdf has some layout issues with tables that prevents it from limiting width when the contents are larger than the cell size. Regarding your solution, you don't need to add `display:block` if your content is contained in a block element. Just be sure to specify a width on the container and style with `word-wrap: break-word;`.